# What is our stance on questions with no prior research but where the OP posted an answer? Leave it open or close as lacking prior research?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

What is our stance on questions with no prior research but where the OP posted an answer? Leave it open or close as lacking prior research?

Examples:

- [Why is it necessary to fast before a procedure involving anesthesia?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/22971/43)
- [What's the typical concentration of medical oxygen?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/20413/43)
- [How can you determine whether a surgical mask is real or fake?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/22827/43)

Answer (score 4):

I think closing such questions would be pedantic in the extreme and completely counter-productive. If you ask a question you intend to answer you have to provide the answer in your question? That's ridiculous. All your examples are questions the OP had clearly thought out in advance and researched with the intent of answering. Their answer ***is*** the prior research.

The very reason SE has always embraced answering your own question is because it's a great way for people to provide answers to questions they've faced themselves and solved themselves before anyone ever even asked.